# React Redux History error - TypeError: (0 , _history2.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, history, redux

History 2.0.0-rc2

Followed [this example](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#getting-started) verbatim and:

```
import { createHistory }  from 'history';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { syncHistory } from 'react-router-redux';

const history = createHistory(); //<-- ***THIS LINE IS FAILING!!!***
const routingMiddleware = syncHistory(history);
```

...creating history is failing with `TypeError: (0 , _history2.default) is not a function`. I've tried without the {} and tried importing it from createBrowserHistory as well with the same result. What am I missing? I opened a but against History but they said we don't look into bugs so please post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

OK - apparently for now push, replace, etc have to be called from react-router instead of react-router-redux (formerly redux-simple-router). Anyway, I am going back to the 1.x version of them all since those worked.

@Brandon - FYI- I did have the right History version. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your npm package for `history`.

Try running `npm ls|grep history` to see what version you have installed.  Ensure you are really on the latest version (2.0.0-rc2).

You can also try deleting `node_modules/history` and reinstalling it.